# How to remove MUI 5 Card Action Area Default Hover State

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This question has probably been answered but i cant seem to find a solution.

I want to remove the default hover state on the CardActionArea component from mui 5. When i hover over the action area, there is a light grey background that i want to remove. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<Grid container spacing={2}>
  {todos.map((todo) => (
    <Grid key={todo.db_id} item xs={12} md={4}>
      <Card variant='outlined' sx={{ minWidth: 200 }}>
        <CardActionArea onClick={() => handleRedirect(todo.db_id)}>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography variant='h4' color='text.secondary' gutterBottom>
              {todo.title}
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </CardActionArea>
        <CardActions>
          <Button
            onClick={() => deleteHandler(todo.db_id)}
            variant='contained'
            size='small'
          >
            Delete
          </Button>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
    </Grid>
  ))}
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the styled-components engine for MUI 5, so my answer will be based on that, but I was able to remove the grey hover by accessing the `.MuiCardActionArea-focusHighlight`, as described on this page:

https://mui.com/material-ui/api/card-action-area/

I was able to remove it with the following code:

```js
const StyledCardActionArea = styled(CardActionArea)(({theme}) => `
    .MuiCardActionArea-focusHighlight {
        background: transparent;
    }
`);
```

Then just put that component in place of `CardActionArea` within your code.